# Derivative of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

In [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/486234), we can see:

$$ \phi: \beta \mapsto \Vert y - X \beta \Vert^2 = \Vert y \Vert^2 - 2 y^T X \beta + \beta^T X^T X \beta $$

$$ \dfrac {\partial \phi} {\partial \beta} = \beta^TX^TX + X^TX\beta$$

$$ \dfrac {\partial^2 \phi} {\partial \beta^2} = 2X^TX$$

I am confused howto get the first derivative. I understand that $\Vert y \Vert^2$ is gone because it is a scalar, but I don't understand the rest.

Can someone explain it to me or redirect me to a good resource if this is a property or something?

Thank you.

Comment: Expand the squared norm as an inner product and use the definition of a  derivative

Comment: That first derivative at your link isn't even correct. The dimensions of $\beta^TX^TX$ and $X^TX\beta$ don't match for one.

Comment: I have edited the relevant answer at the included link and corrected first derivative. It should be $- 2y^TX + 2\beta^TX^TX$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\phi(\beta) &= (y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)\\
         &=y'y + \beta'X'X\beta - 2\beta' X'y,
\end{align}
where $X'X=A$ is a square matrix of order (rank) $p+1$, thus $\beta' X'X\beta = \beta' A \beta$ is quadratic form, as such you can rewrite it in the following manner
$$
\beta' A \beta = \sum_j\sum_i \beta_j \beta_ia_{ij} = \sum\beta_j^2a_{jj} + 2\sum_{i < j}\beta_i \beta_j a_{ij},
$$
taking derivative w.r.t. $\beta$ you'll get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (\beta' A \beta) = 2\sum_j \beta_j a_{jj} + 2 \sum_{i < j} \beta_ja_{ij} = 2A\beta,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (\beta' X'X \beta) = 2X'X\beta. 
$$

Note that $X'X\beta$ can be expressed as 
$$
X'X\beta = \sum_{j=1}^{p+1} C_j(X'X)\beta_j,
$$
where $C_j(X'X)$ is the $j$-th column of $X'X$. Taking derivative w.r.t. $\beta_j$ will leave you only with the $j$-th column any time, hence, 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (X'X\beta) = [C_1(X'X),..., C_2(X'X)] = X'X
$$

Comment: How do you get $-2\beta X'y$? Wouldn't it be $-2yX\beta$?

Comment: And why the order does not matter here?

Comment: Because it is scalar, so you can transpose it and it won't change

Comment: that means $-2\beta X'y = -2yX\beta$?

Comment: $y'X\beta = \beta' X' y$

Answer (score 1):

Rather than expand and then differentiate, do the differentiation first.

Define the vector $z=(X\beta-y)$ and write the function as an inner product, which I'll denote with a colon for ease of typing. Then it's simple to find the differential, the gradient, and the Hessian
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= z:z \cr
d\phi &= 2z:dz &= 2z:X\,d\beta = 2X^Tz:d\beta \cr
g=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\beta} &= 2X^Tz &= 2X^T(X\beta-y) \cr
dg &= 2X^T dz &= 2X^TX\,d\beta \cr
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial\beta} &= 2X^TX \cr
}$$

Comment: Could you explain why $dz = Xd\beta$?

Comment: @BagusTrihatmaja In general, the differential of $z$ is $$dz=dX\,\beta + X\,d\beta - dy$$ but you are interested in the change in the value of the function due to changing $\beta$, so $X$ and $y$ are treated as constants.