# Proof of convexity of linear least squares with convexity properties

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, least-squares

I have seen some posts proving the linear least squares convexity using the second derivative ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483339/proof-of-convexity-of-linear-least-squares)) but I was trying to demonstrate its convexity with convex properties.

Below is my deduction. Having:

$$ y(x,w) = w_0 + w_1x + w_2x^2+...+w_Mx^M $$
$$ E(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} [y(x_i,w) - t_i]^2 $$

Composition with an affine mapping is convex (if $f(z)$ is convex  $f(Az+b)$ is convex). As $y(x,w) - t$ is linear on $w$ and $f(z)=z^2$ is convex. Then $[y(x,w) - t]^2$ is convex.

If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are convex then $f(z) + g(z)$ is convex. So $\sum_{i=1}^{N} [y(x_{i},w) - t_i]^2$ is convex.

If $f(z)$ is convex, $cf(z)$ is convex for $c>0$. Then $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} [y(x_{i},w) - t_i]^2$ is convex.

Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct, albeit confusing since you first treat $x$ as data and later as a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have replaced it with z

Comment: Shouldn't $x$ be $x_i$ and shouldn't $t_n$ be $t_i$?

Comment: Right, solved too