# Matrix Calculus in Least-Square method (Why setting first order derivatives to be zero guarantees it is minimum)

Tags: least-squares

Assume V + Ax = b is the equation where V is the vectors of residuals, A is the matrix for coefficients, x is the vector for unknowns, and b is the vector for observation.

It is common to read something like "The least squares estimator is obtained by minimizing V. Therefore we set the partial derivative of V^(t)V with respective to x equal to zero..."

What I don't understand is that by doing so, we may actually find a maximum point for V instead of minimum, since we haven't check for the sign in both direction. Why they can just assume getting a minimum point?

Comment: Because the linear least squares objective function (which is not the V you show) is convex.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any proof by Hessian matrix that proving the second derivative of V^(t) V with respect to X^t is positive defined? I spend a lot of time to find but I couldn't.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483339/proof-of-convexity-of-linear-least-squares